# foreach dictionary to check derived class

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach, getter-setter, gettype

I have a **base class** `Rules.cs`. There are 2 derived classes `RowRules.cs` and `ColumnRules.cs`. I have another class `Test.cs`. This class has a `Dictionary <int, Rules>` which keeps adding the values. When I loop through the dictionary I need to know if the value is a RowRule or a ColumnRule. To better understand I have the code below.

**Rules.cs**

```
class Rules
{
    private int m_timepointId = 0;
    private int m_studyId = 0;

    public int TimepointId
    {
        get { return m_timepointId; }
        set { m_timepointId = value;}
    }

    public int StudyId
    {    
        get { return m_studyId; }
        set {m_studyId = value; }
    }
}
```

**RowRules.cs**

```
class RowRules : Rules
{
   private int m_row;

   public int Row
   {
       get { return m_row; }
       set { m_row = value; }
   }
}
```

**ColumnRules.cs**

```
class ColumnRules: Rules
{
    private int m_column;

    public int Column
    {
        get { return m_column; }
        set { m_column = value; }
    }
}
```

In the **`main class`** I have

```
private Dictionary<int, Rules> m_testDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Rules>();
ColumnRules columnrules = new ColumnRules();
RowRules rowRules = new RowRules();

rowRules.Row = 1;
rowRules.StudyId = 1;
m_testDictionary.Add(1, rowRules);

columnRules.Column = 2;
columnRules.TimepointId = 2;
m_testDictionary.Add(2, columnRules);
foreach(.... in m_testDictionary)
{
     //Need code here.
    //if(... ==  RowRules)
      {

      }
}
```

Now, I need to know what value will go in the `foreach` loop. Also, I need to know whether that particular dictionary row is a `RowRule` or a `ColumnRule`. Hope I am clear with the question. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you're testing for types, there's a good chance that a `virtual` (or `abstract`) method in the base class is the way to go.

Comment: @dlev totally agree - their interface from this perspective should be the same. Only the behaviour behind that interface should be different - but the main class shouldn't know or care about that...

Comment: @Vinay I recommend you post this code to a new thread over on codereview.stackexchange.com. I'm sure you'll receive some very useful pointers on appropriate use of inheritance :)

Comment: Thanks @MattDavey. Any improvements to the code is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int, Rules> pair in m_testDictionary)
{
    if(pair.Value is RowRule)
    {
         // do row rule stuff
    }
    if(pair.Value is ColumnRule)
    {
         // do row column rule stuff
    }
}
```

Here is more information on the [`is` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 I came up with an identical solution, but you got it quicker.

Comment: For posterity - please view this answer in conjunction with @dlev's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

There are a bunch of answers that are telling you to test the type using "is". That's fine, but in my opinion if you're switching off the type of an object, you're probably doing something wrong.

Typically, derived classes are used when you need additional and varied functionality from a base class. Moreover, ad-hoc polymorphism via `virtual` and `abstract` methods means that you can let the *run-time* figure out the type, leading to significantly cleaner code.

For example, in your case, you might want to make `Rules` an `abstract` class, with an `abstract ApplyRule()` method. Then, each subclass can implement the method, with the full knowledge of what it means to be a rule of that type:

```
public class Rules
{
    private int m_timepointId = 0;
    private int m_studyId = 0;

    public int TimepointId
    {
        get { return m_timepointId; }
        set { m_timepointId = value;}
    }

    public int StudyId
    {    
        get { return m_studyId; }
        set {m_studyId = value; }
    }

    // New method
    public abstract void ApplyRule();
}

class RowRules : Rules
{
   private int m_row;

   public int Row
   {
       get { return m_row; }
       set { m_row = value; }
   }

   public override void ApplyRule() { // Row specific implementation }
}

class ColumnRules : Rules
{
    private int m_column;

    public int Column
    {
        get { return m_column; }
        set { m_column = value; }
    }

   public override void ApplyRule() { // Column specific implementation }
}
```

Now, your loop is just:

```
foreach(var kvp in m_testDictionary)
{
    kvp.Value.ApplyRule();
}
```

Comment: +1 for seeing past the simple question to the underlying problem :)

Comment: I understand what you are saying here. But for my scenario, the timepointid and studyid and just 2 values. There are a bunch of them and they are all required. Only thing different will be either it belongs to a row or a column. There is not much implementation there other than loading the values to a list and leaving out either the column or row value null.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
foreach(var rule in in m_testDictionary.Values)
{
  var rowRules = rule as RowRules;
  if (rowRules != null) {
    // It's a RowRules
    continue;
  }

  var columnRules = rule as ColumnRules;
  if (columnRules != null) {
    // It's a ColumnRules
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this is the answer to the question, it's worth pointing out that this approach is in fact an abuse of inheritance. The containing class shouldn't need to differentiate between RowRule and ColumnRule in order to treat them differently - it violates the Liskov Substituion principle..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
foreach(var key in m_testDictionary.Keys)
{
   var value = m_testDictionary[key];
   if(value is RowRules)
   {
      //test your code.....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does that code work? You have added the same key twice I believe. This is the code you wanted I believe:

```
foreach(int key in m_testDictionary.Keys)
{
    RowRules row = m_testDictionary[key] as RowRules;
    if(row !=null)
      {

            //code here:)
      }
}
```

Comment: ahh the old is-as trap! see http://ekrishnakumar.wordpress.com/2006/07/08/c-is-and-as-operators/

Comment: The more idiomatic pattern is to have `var x = otherVar as SomeType; if (x != null) { // Do stuff with x }`

Comment: Thanks Matt - I'll remember that for next time!